# How set button reply the same command that user typed Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I added a command called "Facts" in my bot. So it replies with a embed. now I want to add a button bellow it cz user dont have to type the fact command they type it once and button will appear the embed. now how can i set button to reply the same command?

```
    if(commandName === 'facts'){
      try{
        const factsRow = new MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
              .setLabel('More Facts')
              .setStyle('primary')
            )
         
        const mavlina = new Mavlina()
        const factsd = await mavlina.facts()
         // embed
         const factsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
         .setColor('#111133')
         
         .setTitle("Facts")
         .setDescription(`${factsd.data}`)

       // sending reply
       interaction.reply({
        components: [factsRow],
         embeds: [ factsEmbed ],
         ephemeral: true
       })
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
      }
   }
```

I want to add a button bellow it cz user dont have to type the fact command they type it once and button will appear the embed. now how can i set button to reply the same command?

Comment: you can't really do that but you can make it edit the message that was sent from the command with `interaction.update` and it will still have the reply

Comment: @DragosPV but how do other bots do this?

Answer (score 0):

From Discord.js docs, there's a [Message#awaitMessageComponent](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitMessageComponent) you can use this to get a button interaction from the message. Well interaction is not a message, we can fix that simply by adding a single code! interaction.fetchReply() will return a Message object so you can use that (note that it will return a Promise so await it) Once you get the button interaction you can do whatever you want to do

Your code would be something like this

```js
 new MessageButton()
              .setLabel('More Facts')
              .setStyle('primary')
              .setCustomId('button') //required for getting the interaction
...
interaction.reply({
        components: [factsRow],
         embeds: [ factsEmbed ],
         ephemeral: true
       })
const message = await interaction.fetchReply()

const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'button'
message.awaitMessageComponent({ filter, time: 15000 })
  .then(interaction => console.log(`${interaction.customId} was clicked!`))
  .catch(console.error);
//Edit as your wish
```

Comment: @lspik thanks bro but I solve it last night. But now there is another thing if anyone clicks the button for more facts the bot sends a new embed with the button more facts. But how can I hide the previous embed button when someone clicked a new one? An example they did : https://streamable.com/i88xxr